# Angular material $mdthemingprovider dynamic themes

Tags: angular-material, angular-providers

I'm trying to put dynamic themes, but I can not spend scopes, variables for $mdthemingprovider.

The way that I thought was a provider with my resource, but have no idea how to create one.

I have 2 forms that I use today, which are $rootScope and $cacheFactory, where I keep my global variables to access throughout the app. But at $mdthemingprovider does not accept neither.